# Bug? Answers not shown on some questions in search

Tags: support, search

I have long been using the `answers:1` filter to limit search results to questions with answers, but it seems that it does not always work as described.

For example, [this SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine) returns 18 hits, with the topmost 3 having 4, 2, and 1 answers respectively, but those answers are not indicated on the search results:

[image: Screen capture]

And sure enough, when I add `answers:1` ([this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine%20answers%3A1)), those questions are not included in the results.

Is it a bug?
How do I search for questions that have answers without excluding those?

**Edit:**

Thanks to Shadow The Spring Wizard's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389718/153139), I understand that the first query finds both questions and answers containing the search terms, while the second finds only questions.

So the question remains: what is the syntax to search for both answers and questions with answers?  I tried `AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine (answers:1 or is:question)` but it did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually search for both answered questions and answers. `answer:n` and `isanswered:yes` return only questions, and `is:answer` returns only answers. Trying to combine them leads to the post type of the second condition to be ignored, so ` isanswered:yes is:answer` or ` answers:1 is:answer` return only questions. This actually is a bug in the interface, which for the second query says "Search options **answers only not deleted answers>= 1**" which is not true because it is not "answers only", it is "questions only". Probably this is already reported somewhere, I'll check.

Comment: Hm actually I can't find anything, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423090/how-to-show-questions-and-answers-in-search-results is the closest, not really the same issue, but maybe the same underlying implementation limitation.

Answer (score 7):

Not a bug.

The `answers:X` operator is used to find questions, if X is 0 it will return questions with no answers, if X is more than 0 it will return questions having X or more answers. But it will return only questions.

You can use `is:a` to get back only answers.

For more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: The problem is that it does not return some *questions*.  Like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23072223/181238.  Oh I see, the search string is not in the question.

Comment: @AlexO so all is clear and good now? :-)

Comment: Almost, see edit.

Comment: @AlexO sadly, pretty sure there isn't such a way, at least with the ordinary search. Might look into the custom filters or Filtered Questions on se.com but it might get complex. (And of course, last resort is SEDE.)